# Displaying random image with JS from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far it doesn't display anything. I'm guessing I'm missing something with src but I don't quite get it yet.

```js
function display_pic() {
  var arr_images = [
    './assets/arb_01.png',
    './assets/arb_02.png',
    './assets/arb_03.png'
  ];

  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr_images.length);

  $('.random_image').css({
    'background': arr_images[index],
    'background-position': '100%',
  });

}

window.onload = display_pic();
```

Comment: Your 'HTML' was the JS copied twice. I edited the question to remove it.

Comment: Regarding the issue, you're setting a CSS properties named `theimage` and `theimage-position`. These do not exist and will have no effect. If you want to set the `img` source, set the `src` property.

Comment: To set a background the value needs to be in the format: `url('path/to/yourimage.jpg)`